# How do I stop material being stretched?

Tags: materials, transforms

[image]All I have done is scale a square along the y-axis and applied a material to it. The material is being stretched along the y-axis. How do I stop this?
I have applied all transforms but it's made no difference.

Comment: Hello, could you please show a screenshot of your Shader Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to UV-unrap the object again after applying the scale.

Comment: Cheers, I added a texture coordinate in front of the noise texture and it's sorted it.